# Class google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata hasn't been added to descriptor pool

Tags: php, grpc, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm getting this error when trying to resume a Speech to Text operation.

`Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBDecodeException: Error occurred during parsing: Class google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata hasn't been added to descriptor pool in Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message->parseFromJsonStream()`

What I'm doing is starting the longrunning operation and storing the name.   Later I'm creating a separate page with the status of the operation based on the name I stored previously.

This is what I'm using to try and get the operation status

```
$speechClient = new SpeechClient();
$operationResponse = $speechClient->resumeOperation($record->operation_name, 'longRunningRecognize');
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 6):

This took me way too long to figure out for such a simple fix, but here you go.

Put this line before calling `resumeOperation`:

`\GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\CloudSpeech::initOnce();`.

I think this is a bug within the SDK, but considering their docs say the client libraries are in Alpha, it makes sense.

---

A longer explanation (since it took me so darn long, and I know I'll find my SO answer in the future if I run into this problem again):

The DocBlocks above the `SpeechGapicClient::longRunningRecognize()` method show an alternative to blocking polling with `$operation->pollUntilComplete()`

```php
// start the operation, keep the operation name, and resume later
$operationResponse = $speechClient->longRunningRecognize($config, $audio);
$operationName = $operationResponse->getName();
// ... do other work
$newOperationResponse = $speechClient->resumeOperation($operationName, 'longRunningRecognize');
while (!$newOperationResponse->isDone()) {
    // ... do other work
    $newOperationResponse->reload();
}
if ($newOperationResponse->operationSucceeded()) {
    $result = $newOperationResponse->getResult();
    // doSomethingWith($result)
} else {
    $error = $newOperationResponse->getError();
    // handleError($error)
}
```

Everything works great if you call `resumeOperation()` on the same operation returned by the `longRunningRecognize()` method. If you try to resume in a separate request, as you and I did, we get the error you mentioned above.

The difference is, the `longRunningRecognize()` method creates a request (`LongRunningRecognizeRequest`) which is executed whereas `resumeOperation()` is pretty straight forward and doesn't need to combine request parameters for sending to Google.

The difference here is, the constructor of the `LongRunningRecognizeRequest` calls `\GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\CloudSpeech::initOnce();` which sets up the needed speech descriptors.

---

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this almost solved the problem. Just make sure to use "LongRunningRecognize" as resume operation method's argument and not "longRunningRecognize" (first letter should be uppercase) - otherwise the response is protobuf encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, trying to get information about an operation (`getOperation`):

Google\Protobuf\Internal\**GPBDecodeException**
Error occurred during parsing: Class **google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata hasn't been added to descriptor pool**

As @stevenwadejr already answered correctly, this can be solved by calling initOnce() before the call.

```
<?php
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1p1beta1\SpeechClient;
use GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Speech\V1P1Beta1\CloudSpeech;

$client = new SpeechClient();

// This line is required. It adds LongRunningRecognizeMetadata and others to the pool of recognized classes
CloudSpeech::initOnce();

// Now, I can get the operation without raising an exception
$operation = $client->getOperationsClient()->getOperation('1234567890123456789');
```

You can check file *\vendor\google\protobuf\src\Google\Protobuf\Internal\AnyBase.php* function `unpack()`. Without the initOnce command the pool variable did not have the fully_qualifed_name (*google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata*) in the `$proto->proto_to_class` array.